# Should we prefer the contradiction tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I suggested this [tag synonym](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags/textual-discrepancies/synonyms) relationship:

[contradiction](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction) => [textual-discrepancies](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-discrepancies)

But [it sounds like](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/294/68) the other way around would be better.

Vote up if you want to reverse the synonym relationship to:

[textual-discrepancies](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-discrepancies) => [contradiction](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradiction)

Vote down if you want to leave things the way they are.

And provide in an answer any related suggestions such as [discrepancies](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrepancies), etc.

Comment: I prefer we use [tag:contradiction] - it is easer to spell and Google, and speaking as someone who doesn't believe true contradictions exist, I don't find the tag at all a problem, because the *subject* certainly exists.

Comment: @Jack: It seems the consensus is that we _do_ prefer [tag:contradiction].  Can we reverse the synonym?  (I can't suggest it at all now.)

Comment: Figured it out - it is now reversed, thanks for raising this here.